# 'HttpClient' object has no attribute 'execute' clickhouse python

Tags: python, clickhouse

I'm trying to execute a command with Clickhouse client in Python as I have seen it in the document but it keeps give me an error
'HttpClient' object has no attribute 'execute'

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client

CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_HOSTNAME = 'localhost'
CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_USER = 'username'
CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_PASSWORD = 'password'
client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(
    host=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_HOSTNAME, port=8123, username=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_USER, password=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_PASSWORD)


import random
data=[]
import datetime

 
# using now() to get current time
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()


for x in range(1000):
    data.append({x, get_random_string(random.randint(5, x+6)),get_random_string(random.randint(5, x+6)),get_random_string(random.randint(5, x+6)),current_time})

client.execute("INSERT INTO test FORMAT JSONEachRow", data)
```

. Stack trace:

0. DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0x000000000bfc4fe4 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception(PreformattedMessage&&, int) @ 0x00000000075f8360 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
2. DB::AccessControl::authenticate(DB::Credentials const&, Poco::Net::IPAddress const&) const @ 0x00000000102190bc in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::Session::authenticate(DB::Credentials const&, Poco::Net::SocketAddress const&) @ 0x00000000112e0698 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::TCPHandler::runImpl() @ 0x00000000121a3620 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::TCPHandler::run() @ 0x00000000121b4d28 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
6. Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x00000000146bc044 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
7. Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x00000000146bd540 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
8. Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x000000001482ee3c in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
9. Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) @ 0x000000001482cfe4 in /opt/bitnami/clickhouse/bin/clickhouse
10. start_thread @ 0x0000000000007648 in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
11. ? @ 0x00000000000d1fdc in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so

Comment: cannot reproduce. works fine for me. Are you sure you are executing exactly that code?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I have edit it and add stack trace with another code

Comment: Really? Your original code isn't even the same as your current code.   If you used your current code (as posted), ```clickhouse_connect.get_client()``` returns a ```HTTPClient```.  which doesn't have an ```execute()``` method.  You either use ```client = clickhouse_driver.Client()``` or explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks man, I didn't notice that. it's working now